# AngularJS - Deploy on Heroku

Tags: heroku

I created a app for Angular manually, his structure and all stuff.
To run it locally I'm using [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server).

How can I deploy it to Heroku in order to inform what server to run (probably in Procfile)?

Comment: If your app consist only of the `Angular.js` application (i.e. you are either not using or using a 3rd party API for fetching data), then you need only to do a `git push`, once you do that the `angular` app should be available for use.

Comment: I tried it, but I get the error commented below.

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: I solve the problem with a workaround, I deployed a Yeoman project and changed the content to my project, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Procfile` just called Procfile (no extension) in the root of your app.  Within that file use `web:` to tell heroku what to run.  For example:

```
web: coffee server.coffee
```

Comment: When I use $ git push heroku master, I got the error: Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack.

Comment: What are you using to serve the files?

Comment: I solve the problem with a workaround, I deployed a Yeoman project and changed the content to my project, now it works.